# Search for terms by name in admin panel

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

Right now I only see a way to list all the terms of a particular taxonomy in the admin panel. I have to go through pages of terms if I want to locate a term I want to edit. How can I search by a term's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create view for your needs. Access only to admin role and pin it to "Default Shortcuts" menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Taxonomy Manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager)

Comment: I can search through that but I don't think there's an easy way to go to the term edit page